# Umlaut in plots only if Octave script file is in UTF8

Tags: windows, utf-8, octave, diacritics

I used Octave 6 on Windows to plot figures with (german) umlauts like "Ä", "ö" and "ü" in the command line mode (octave started not in the gui mode).

Now I tried recent Octave 8.1.0 and if I run on the command line the following script with character encoding "Latin1" (according to Notepad++)...

```
graphics_toolkit("qt");
x=1:10;
plot(x, x);
title('Ä Ö Ü');
xlabel('H_2 in µm ');
ylabel('Percent in %');
print("test_umlaute8_latin1_qt.png");
```

I get the warnings...

> warning: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequences have been replaced.
> warning: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequences have been replaced.

and the following image not showing the Umlauts
[image]

If I convert the above script to UTF8 using Notepad++ and run octave again on the command line, the umlauts are displayed properly in the image:
[image]

I had Octave umlauts problems years ago and the solution was to use latin1 and not use UTF8 since the Octave UTF8 support was by accident as I remember. I have not found hints in the release notes about encoding changes like UTF8.

Do you know if using UTF8 is save now? Then I would convert the scripts to utf8 and hope that i would not get UTF8 problems in the future.

Comment: `If I run on the command line the following script with character encoding "ANSI"` don't. Windows is a natively Unicode OS, since the very first Windows NT version in 1994. NTFS is Unicode. ANSI isn't Latin1, it's the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage that doesn't allow any diacritics. `the solution was to use ansi (latin1)` no, that only covered up the problems of the application or code you used to load that file with the wrong codepage

Comment: Octave uses UTF-8 as its internal encoding as well (see [docs](https://docs.octave.org/v8.1.0/Stringencoding.html)) so it should be the preferred input encoding in my opinion.

Comment: Use either UTF16 or UTF8.  When reading a text file, it's the application that specifies what encoding to use. Some encodings, eg UTF16, include a Byte Order Mark at the start that tells applications what encoding is used (UTF16LE, UTF16BT, UTF32, UTF8). In other cases the application or the libraries it uses use a default encoding. Nowadays, that's UTF8. 20 years ago, where Windows 9x/Millenium was still common, the default was to use the user's collation or "system locale", which the Settings page calls `Encoding used for non-Unicode applications`.

Comment: Another option is to set that "system" locale to 65001 - UTF8. Be careful though, there are some applications that expect this to be a single-byte codepage and can choke on multi-byte characters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Your are right, I used "ansi" the wrong way in my description. All my files have the latin1 encoding and also do not work with umlaut.

Comment: Latin1 does have umlauts. The application is using a different encoding to read the data though. The `�` character is the [Unicode Replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character), used when trying to read *non*-Unicode text with a codepage that has no matching symbol for a specific byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments say using only UTF-8 in the scripts and functions seems to be the way to go.